# Overloading assignment operation/stream

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, overloading

I want to know if the following code which is meant to do operations on rational numbers actually already overloads assignment operations and stream insertion operator << to print objects. I'm not very good with C++ so this is new to me but from what I can tell I think it already does.

```
    /*
 *
 *  C++ version
 *
 */

/* rational.h */

#ifndef RATIONAL_H
#define RATIONAL_H

#include <iostream>

using std::ostream;

struct rational {

    rational(int = 0, int = 1);

    rational operator+(const rational &) const;
    rational operator-(const rational &) const;
    rational operator*(const rational &) const;
    rational operator/(const rational &) const;

    rational operator+(int) const;
    rational operator-(int) const;
    rational operator*(int) const;
    rational operator/(int) const;

    friend rational operator+(int, const rational &);
    friend rational operator-(int, const rational &);
    friend rational operator*(int, const rational &);
    friend rational operator/(int, const rational &);

    friend ostream &operator<<(ostream &, const rational &);

private:

    int den;
    int num;
};

#endif /* RATIONAL_H */

/* rational.cc */

#include <iostream>
#include "rational.h"

rational::rational(int num, int den) : num(num), den(den) {}

rational rational::operator+(const rational &o) const {

    return rational(num * o.den + o.num * den, den * o.den);
}

rational rational::operator+(int n) const {

    return rational(num + n * den, den);
}

rational rational::operator-(const rational &o) const {

    return rational(num * o.den - o.num * den, den * o.den);
}

rational rational::operator-(int n) const {

    return rational(num - n * den, den);
}

rational rational::operator*(const rational &o) const {

    return rational(num * o.num, den * o.den);
}

rational rational::operator*(int n) const {

    return rational(num * n, den);
}

rational rational::operator/(const rational &o) const {

    return rational(num * o.den, den * o.num);
}

rational rational::operator/(int n) const {

    return rational(num, den * n);
}

rational operator+(int n, const rational &o) {

    return o + n;
}

rational operator-(int n, const rational &o) {

    return rational(n) - o;
}

rational operator*(int n, const rational &o) {

    return o * n;
}

rational operator/(int n, const rational &o) {

    return rational(n) / o;
}

ostream &operator<<(ostream &out, const rational &o) {

    out << '(' << o.num << " / " << o.den << ')';
    return out;
}

/* main.cc */

#include <iostream>
#include "rational.h"

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

int main(void) {

    rational a(1, 2);
    rational b(2, 3);

    int i = 5;

    cout << a << " + " << b << " = " << a + b << endl;
    cout << a << " - " << b << " = " << a - b << endl;
    cout << a << " * " << b << " = " << a * b << endl;
    cout << a << " / " << b << " = " << a / b << endl;

    cout << a << " + " << i << " = " << a + i << endl;
    cout << a << " - " << i << " = " << a - i << endl;
    cout << a << " * " << i << " = " << a * i << endl;
    cout << a << " / " << i << " = " << a / i << endl;

    cout << i << " + " << a << " = " << i + a << endl;
    cout << i << " - " << a << " = " << i - a << endl;
    cout << i << " * " << a << " = " << i * a << endl;
    cout << i << " / " << a << " = " << i / a << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `operator<<` is ok (you can write it in one line though, but it doesn’t matter here):

```
ostream &operator<<(ostream &out, const rational &o) {
    return out << '(' << o.num << " / " << o.den << ')';
}
```

However, you haven’t defined assignment operators yet!

```
rational & rational::operator=(rational const &rhs) {
    den = rhs.den;
    num = rhs.num;
    return *this;
}
```

Comment: I just need one function(the one you provided)?

Comment: You can use the `operator=` I gave you, yes. The version of alestanis also works now, but the `this->` is optional (he must be from Java world ;) )

Comment: well, you shouldn’t use the same name for ctor params and attributes. It will work with some compilers, and will crash as shit on others. Prefer the below:

Comment: `rational::rational(int n, int d) : num(n), den(d) {}`

Comment: @skp: Using the same name will work on all conformant compilers.

Comment: I’m pretty sure some ones will just not even warn on it, but a strange runtime behavior will occur. Anyway, it’s not a good advice to tell him to keep that way of doing ;)

Comment: btw thanks for the edit, I’m too used to writting D `return this` reference :)

Comment: hmm thank you. I'm hoping you can help me with my next question. I tried running this program and i'm getting some errors:

main.cpp:11: error: `rational' was not declared in this scope
main.cpp:11: error: expected `;' before "a"
main.cpp:12: error: expected `;' before "b"
main.cpp:16: error: `a' was not declared in this scope
main.cpp:16: error: `b' was not declared in this scope

I don't know what the problem is : /

Comment: have you included the `rational.h` header file? Also, please feel free to create another question for that « issue » on stack and post the link here ;)

Comment: Actually, I think I fixed it but in the process I received some errors related to the line where I added the code you provided. Maybe you would know what the problem is?

rational.cpp:8: error: definition of implicitly-declared `rational& rational::operator=(const rational&)'
rational.cpp:8: error: declaration of `rational& rational::operator=(const rational&)' throws different exceptions
rational.h:16: error: than previous declaration `rational& rational::operator=(const rational&) throw ()'

Comment: @skp Using the same name for parameters and members in a constructor is a widely used idiom, and is perfectly correct and portable.

Comment: @user1880760 If you want to define an assignment operator, you also have to declare it in the class.  For classes like this, however, it is probably preferable to simply let the compiler do it.

Comment: how do I let the compiler do it?

Comment: depends. In C++03, you nothing to do. In C++11, use the `operator=() = default`.

Answer (score 2):

**Short answer:** yes it does for `<<` and arithmetic operations.
It doesn't for assignment.

For example, this is the `<<` overloading:

```
ostream &operator<<(ostream &out, const rational &o) {
    out << '(' << o.num << " / " << o.den << ')';
    return out;
}
```

To overload the [assignment operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_operator_%28C++%29), you should write a function

```
rational& rational::operator=(const rational &o) {
    this->den = o.den;
    this->num = o.num;
    return *this;
}
```

Comment: your assignment operator can’t be used in assignment chain or in a loop/if statement. Plus, you can’t declare it as const since it mutates this.

Comment: The assignment operator is totally unnecessary and superfluous.

Answer (score 0):

Both insertion and assignment are fine.  The assignment operator
(and the copy constructor) are provided by the compiler, which
is fine in this case.  If for some reason you do want to provide
an assignment operator (or you need to for some other class),
you almost certainly need to provide a copy constructor as well,
and most of the time, a destructor.  But that's not the case
here; the compiler generated versions are fine (and what most
C++ programmers would expect, I think).

With regards to the other comments on your code: the way you
have written the constructor and the insertion operator is just
fine, and is preferable to the suggested alternatives.